# Firebase MFA to allow sign in and only ask for MFA when accessing sensitive data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I am currently looking to add Firebase multi-factor authentication (via SMS) to my web app.

However, I don't want the MFA challenge to be asked at login. I want users to be able to log in (via username and password) and only request an MFA challenge when they attempt to access/modify sensitive information.

After creating a prototype, Firebase throws the error `auth/multi-factor-auth-required` after login (which is expected) but I haven't been able to find a way to skip the initial MFA check for it to be asked later (when I require it).

Is there any way to implement what I'm asking?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience so far working with MFA, MFA is done for account level and not just action level, so making it work only for certain actions is not possible from my limited knowledge. What I do is , throw an firebase error code for reauthorization for certain actions which forces user to reauth themselves through whatever flow you are implementing and then letting proceed with action. It has its user experiences drawbacks but works fine. Refer to firebase error codes for throwing a recent login error code and then implement your flow..